# How do I bring an object forward in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im having this problem where I cannot bring a few objects forward in Unity 2D, such as a character being behind a background. Im trying my best by changing the layer order, but that doesn't seem to be working. Im new to Unity, could I please have some help?[Layer of character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBeNW.png)

Ive tried changing the order of layer, making a custom hierarchy and thats it because I cant think of anything else.[Layer of backdrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4JGP.png)

Comment: I can't be sure because of lack of information, but maybe layer order don't work because you try to apply it to different layers? "Default" and "Backdrop" are different layers on your screenshots. You can try to put your objects in different order in the hierarchy window but not in layer order? Like put object you want to bring forward higher in hierarchy? Try it out

Comment: To add to what @ГлебБуткевич said, yes, order in the hierarchy matters, not just layers. While layers are the "priority" that a Canvas handles UI objects (for example with multiple Canvases) or a Sprite Renderer prioritize sprites, the way that the engine handles objects is done using the hierarchy, just trying to point out that object hierarchy doesn't exclude you needing to keep track of layers (just to make it clear this is what he meant, in case you had doubts), depending on the case. So experiment in combinations with both.

Comment: Hierarchy order only applies when using a canvas.  Most likely the order of the sorting layers is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Order in Hierarchy defines that make sure your character sprite is 1st as child under canvas then other items..